# TextView is gone and Button is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

`Textview` items are not visible. The `Button` below them is.

Tried changing the `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout`, changed the `match_parent` and content with `0dp`. None of them worked. Only the button shows in the right spot as though the TextViews are there but invisible. These views are called in the `onCreate()` of the Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".EnterData">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvDateIn"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        tools:text="Date"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/tvDescIn"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        tools:text="Description"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/tvAmountIn"
        tools:text="California"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:text="Send Data"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please attach one screenshot.

Comment: Did you try to replace "tools:text" with "android:text" in TextViews?

Comment: change **tools:text** with **android:text**

Answer (score 4):

You try to use `android:text` instead of `tools:text`. `tools:text`only visible in the Android Studio.

Or you should use `yourTextView.setText("yourText")` if you are using `tools:text`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tool:text in xml use android:text="abc" in textView.
As tool:text is used for android studio layout preview . It does not show text when you run your application . 
While android:text is used to set text to textview, button etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it was all working and just placing android:text showed it.
Thank you very much.